# Uploading an image to digital ocean (s3Client)

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-s3, next.js, digital-ocean

I'm trying to upload an image to digital ocean spaces.

On client side, I do this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('myFile', file as string)
fetch('/api/upload',
        {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(`response sucess: ${response.status}`)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            // Handle error
});
```

server side (nextJs), I'm to be honest a bit lost..

```
export default async function upload(req: NextApiRequest & { [key: string]: any }, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const multerUpload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });
    await runMiddleware(req, res, multerUpload.single("file"));
    const file = req.body.myFile;
    const { bucket, key, fileName } = req.body;
    const contentHash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(file).digest('hex');
    const content_length = getBytesForContentLength(file)
    const bucketParams = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        Body: file,
        ContentType: getImageType(file),
        ContentLength: content_length, 
        Headers: {
          'X-Amz-Content-SHA256': `hex(${contentHash})`
      }
    };
    try {
        const response = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(bucketParams));
        console.log(response.$metadata);
        console.log("Success");

        //todo: if successful, post the path to the server DB

        res.status(200)

        
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
        res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
```

The referenced functions:

```
function runMiddleware(req: NextApiRequest & {[key: string]: any}, res: NextApiResponse, fn: (...args: any[]) => void): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fn(req, res, (result: any) => {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
          return reject(result);
        }
  
        return resolve(result);
      });
    });
  }
  
  export const config = {
    api: {
      bodyParser: false,
    },
};
```

and

```
function getBytesForContentLength(base64String: string): number {
    // assume that file_str is the base64 encoded file string
    const myBuffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');
    return myBuffer.byteLength
}
```

The error I'm getting is

```
'$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 400,
    requestId: '***',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Code: 'XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch',
  BucketName: '***',
  RequestId: '***',
  HostId: '***'
}
```

XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch, I tried to circumvent this with the manual setting of the X-Amz-Content header, but it didn't help. Also setting the ContentLength is necessary otherwise I get also an error, related to the ContentLength

```
Code: 'MissingContentLength',
  BucketName: '***',
  RequestId: '***',
  HostId: '***'
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

file is a string (base64 encoded). I created a blob out of it and an arrayBuffer from the blob which I type casted to Buffer

```
const base64Response = await fetch(file);

const blob = await base64Response.blob();
const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()

const bucketParams = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        Body: arrayBuffer as Buffer,
};
```